# Google+ does not return user's friend's email address

Tags: ios, google-plus

I am trying to access friendslist of user's google+ account.

I have used this code for this purpose...

```
-(void)getGooglePlusAccounts:(NSString *)notificationNameStr
{
    GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
    plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

    [plusService setAuthorizer:[[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] authentication]];

    GTLQueryPlus *query =
    [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleListWithUserId:@"me"
                                    collection:kGTLPlusCollectionVisible];
    [plusService executeQuery:query
            completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                GTLPlusPeopleFeed *peopleFeed,
                                NSError *error) {
                if (error) {
                    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
                } else {
                    // Get an array of people from GTLPlusPeopleFeed
                    NSArray* peopleList = peopleFeed.items;
                    NSLog(@"peopleList: %@", peopleList);

            }];
}
```

This will gives me UserID, Image, Name but not email.

How can i find the email for the Friend.

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the email address for a friend if that person has not set there email address public.  So the reason you are not getting an email address returned for your friend is because they have not set the email address public.

To fix this tell your friend to set his email address public.  :)

Following quote from the documentation [Google+ api - People](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/people)

> emails[] list  A list of email addresses that this person has,
>   including their Google account email address, and the **public** verified
>   email addresses on their Google+ profile. The plus.profile.emails.read
>   scope is needed to retrieve these email addresses, or the email scope
>   can be used to retrieve just the Google account email address.

Comment: But i dont get email for any friend

Comment: @FallenAngel actualy it is the answer as you cant do that.

Comment: -1 because the API doesn't allow you to do something?  Cant give you a solution if its not possible though the API.

Comment: As @DalmTo has noted - email addresses are protected information requiring additional permission to be given by the account holder. You can't get this for a friend unless you have the friends explicit permission.

Comment: @Prisoner And how do i get the Explicit permission.

Comment: That friend must also have already signed up with your service and permitted access to you.