# Android requesting google plus user email

Tags: android, google-plus, google-oauth

In my android application I request google plus token which I send to server. I want to be able to get user information including his email address in server.

Here's a call that works but doesn't give me email:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleApiClient), "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " " + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PROFILE);
```

With it I only get this information:

```
{

    "id": "11213535252359196332836",
    "name": "Name Surname",
    "given_name": "Name",
    "family_name": "Surname",
    "link": "https://plus.google.com/+laskdjfksdjf",
    "picture": "https://asdfsdafasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfsdaf7c/photo.jpg",
    "gender": "male",
    "locale": "en"

}
```

I found that I need to ask for userinfo.email permission, so I modified my call:

```
GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(googleApiClient), "oauth2:" + Scopes.PLUS_ME + " " + Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN + " " + Scopes.PROFILE + " https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
```

The problem is, that now getToken() call returns me this error:

```
09-16 18:53:57.311: W/System.err(26467): com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at lt.sm.discountcity.GPlus.getServerOnlineToken(GPlus.java:237)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at lt.sm.discountcity.fragments.LoginFragment$5$1.runOnSeparateThread(LoginFragment.java:173)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at lt.smtools.tasks.TaskManager$2.run(TaskManager.java:139)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-16 18:53:57.316: W/System.err(26467):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong and how to solve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14383965/userrecoverableauthexception-needpermission)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google+ does not return user's friend's email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24262227/google-does-not-return-users-friends-email-address)

Comment: I've seen first post and I don't understand how second post is dublicate, because it talks about getting friends email, not the user that has logged in. First post solution puts me in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html

```
void getAndUseAuthTokenBlocking() {
   try {
      // Retrieve a token for the given account and scope. It will always return either
      // a non-empty String or throw an exception.
      final String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Context, String, String)(context, email,      scope);
      // Do work with token.
      ...
      if (server indicates token is invalid) {
          // invalidate the token that we found is bad so that GoogleAuthUtil won't
          // return it next time (it may have cached it)
          GoogleAuthUtil.invalidateToken(Context, String)(context, token);
          // consider retrying getAndUseTokenBlocking() once more
          return;
      }
      return;
   } catch (GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException playEx) {
     Dialog alert = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
         playEx.getConnectionStatusCode(),
         this,
         MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
     ...
   } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException userAuthEx) {
      // Start the user recoverable action using the intent returned by
      // getIntent()
      myActivity.startActivityForResult(
              userAuthEx.getIntent(),
              MY_ACTIVITYS_AUTH_REQUEST_CODE);
      return;
   } catch (IOException transientEx) {
      // network or server error, the call is expected to succeed if you try again later.
      // Don't attempt to call again immediately - the request is likely to
      // fail, you'll hit quotas or back-off.
      ...
      return;
   } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
      // Failure. The call is not expected to ever succeed so it should not be
      // retried.
      ...
      return;
   }
   }
```

Comment: If I add this line: activity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), RC_AUTHORIZATION); into UserRecoverableAuthException catch block, my app starts an infinite loop with google plus signing in, popping accept permissions window and then logging again and again and again and again... and AGAIN!